# How to create custom claims in JWT using spring-authorization-server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm building an OAuth2 authorization server based on the experimental Spring project [Spring Authorization Server](https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-authorization-server)

My use case is quite simple, fetch users from a DB, and based on some properties of the user, set some custom claims in the JWT being produced.
I haven't found a way to do so with Spring Authorization Server, the only way I could work out is to inject a `jwtCustomizer` object as part of the `JwtEncoder` bean definition:

```
  @Bean
  public JwtEncoder jwtEncoder(CryptoKeySource keySource) {
    NimbusJwsEncoder jwtEncoder = new NimbusJwsEncoder(keySource);
    jwtEncoder.setJwtCustomizer((headersBuilder, claimsBuilder) -> {
      // Inject some headers and claims...
    });
    return jwtEncoder;
  }
```

This obviously doesn't give me access to users information, therefore I can't set the claims I need at this point.
Did anyone manage to solve this problem?

Comment: You can set claims when you build `UserDetails` object, in Spring's `UserDetailsService::loadUserByUsername` that you implement

Comment: No you can't, I've tried that. You can set roles and authorities in `UserDetailsService::loadUserByName` but none of the roles and authorities you set ends up in the JWT

Answer (score 19):

[The solution for this is in a test of the library](https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-authorization-server/blob/a30a1692b28915947a001f1e2a6d1e41a550eaa7/oauth2-authorization-server/src/test/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/oauth2/server/authorization/OidcTests.java#L264)

```
    @Bean
    OAuth2TokenCustomizer<JwtEncodingContext> jwtCustomizer() {
        return context -> {
            if (context.getTokenType().getValue().equals(OidcParameterNames.ID_TOKEN)) {
                Authentication principal = context.getPrincipal();
                Set<String> authorities = principal.getAuthorities().stream()
                        .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
                        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
                context.getClaims().claim(AUTHORITIES_CLAIM, authorities);
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: Above bean is setting authorities to the claim but the default NimbusJwsEncoder ignores authorities claim while building jwt.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following way. Though it is Kotlin code, not Java, but approach should be clear:

```kotlin
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenEnhancer

class UserTokenEnhancer : TokenEnhancer {
    
    override fun enhance(accessToken: OAuth2AccessToken,
                         authentication: OAuth2Authentication): OAuth2AccessToken {

        val username = authentication.userAuthentication.name
        val additionalInfo = mapOf( /* populate with some data for given username */ )

        (accessToken as DefaultOAuth2AccessToken).additionalInformation = additionalInfo
        return accessToken
    }
}
```

Then just register bean:

```kotlin
@Bean
fun userTokenEnhancer(): TokenEnhancer {
    return UserTokenEnhancer()
}
```

Comment: TokenEnhancer is not available in Spring Security 5, which seems to be what the project spring-authorization-server is based on. So no, this solution does not apply to my specific case.